# Issuing multiple bash commands from php on remote machine

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I try to issue:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre joe wget
```

on a remote machine from php,

I've been looking around and tried two approaches:

first:

```
session_start();

$command = "ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -i /var/www/.ssh/my-keypair555.pem ubuntu@{$_SESSION['host']} \"sudo apt-get update\"";

echo $command."<br/>";

echo exec($command, $output);

print_r($output);

$command = "ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -i /var/www/.ssh/my-keypair555.pem ubuntu@{$_SESSION['host']} \"sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jre joe wget\"";

echo $command."<br/>";

echo exec($command, $output);

print_r($output);
```

this code doesn't seem to get executed at all,
(The commands get printed but the output array seems empty.)

and secondly:
an adapted version from http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php

```
session_start();

$connection = ssh2_connect($_SESSION['host'], 22, array('hostkey'=>'ssh-rsa'));

if (ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(
    $connection, 
    'ubuntu',
    '/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub',
    '/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa')
    ) {

    $shell = ssh2_shell($connection,"bash"); 

    $cmd = "echo '[start]';sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jre joe wget;echo '[end]'"; 
    $output = user_exec($shell,$cmd); 

    fclose($shell); 

    echo $output."<br/>";

} else {

    die('Public Key Authentication Failed');
}

function user_exec($shell,$cmd) { 
    fwrite($shell,$cmd . "\n"); 
    $output = ""; 
    $start = false; 
    $start_time = time(); 
    $max_time = 900; //time in seconds 
    while(((time()-$start_time) < $max_time)) { 
        $line = fgets($shell); 
        //echo $line;
        if(!strstr($line,$cmd)) { 
            if(preg_match('/\[start\]/',$line)) { 
                $start = true; 
                echo "start";
            }elseif(preg_match('/\[end\]/',$line)) { 
                return $output; 
            }elseif($start){ 
                $output[] = $line; 
                echo $line."<br/>";
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

If I use this code the command:

```
echo '[start]';sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jre joe wget;echo '[end]'
```

does show up if I log in to the machine and issue

```
history
```

but doesn't seem to be executed because if I issue

```
java
```

I get the message that I need to install it.

if I issue

```
!1
```

the apt-get update and apt-get install do get executed properly.

If I run the php file in a browser I get following output:

Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-36-generic x86_64) * Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/ System information as of Sun Feb 8 17:20:45 UTC 2015 System load: 0.69 Processes: 104 Usage of /: 9.8% of 7.74GB Users logged in: 0 Memory usage: 1% IP address for eth0: 10.74.190.178 Swap usage: 0% Graph this data and manage this system at: https://landscape.canonical.com/ Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest: http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud 0 packages can be updated. 0 updates are security updates. Last login: Sun Feb 8 17:20:50 2015 from ec2-54-77-56-210.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com echo '[start]';sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jre joe wget;echo '[end]' ubuntu@ip-10-74-190-178:~$ echo '[start]';sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get in

- a lot of empty lines and now and then a double message like
  alal
  or
  l -l -

-> note that the command is truncated at 'install'

which would explain why the command isn't executed.

Can anyone give me a hand on this one, I've been searching for almost two weeks now and don't seem to progress a lot...

thanks,

Sander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the max_execution_time in php.ini was the issue here.

I debugged the second script with

```
...
}elseif(preg_match('/\[end\]/',$line)) { 
    echo "[end]:".$line;
    return $output; 
}elseif($start){ 
...
```

and

```
    } //while loop
    echo "out of time";
}//function user_exec($shell,$cmd) {
```

and neither got executed in the output of the page in the browser.

the

```
$max_time = 900; //time in seconds
```

wasn't enough and should be proceded with:

```
set_time_limit(900);
```

The original command was executed but whilst executing it the timeout of php stopped the execution.

Also the first script should have suffered from the same issue, it just took to long to execute the commands and php returned in the midst of the execution.

I also, but I don't think this was the cause of the problem used a:

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection,$cmd);
```

in stead of the original

```
fwrite($shell,$cmd . "\n");
```

the total script:

```
<?php

sleep(30);

session_start();

$connection = ssh2_connect($_SESSION['host'], 22, array('hostkey'=>'ssh-rsa'));

if (ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(
    $connection, 
    'ubuntu',
    '/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub',
    '/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa')
    ) {

    $cmd = "echo '[start]';sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jre joe wget;echo '[end]'"; 

    $output = user_exec($connection,$cmd); 

    fclose($shell); 

    ob_end_flush();

    echo $output."Halleluia!!!";

} else {

    die('Public Key Authentication Failed');
}

function user_exec($connection,$cmd) { 
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection,$cmd);

    $output = ""; 
    $start = false; 
    $start_time = time(); 

    set_time_limit(900);

    $max_time = 900; //time in seconds 
    while(((time()-$start_time) < $max_time)) { 
        $line = fgets($stream); 
        if(!strstr($line,$cmd)) { 
            if(preg_match('/\[start\]/',$line)) { 
                $start = true; 
            }elseif(preg_match('/\[end\]/',$line)) { 
                echo "[end]:".$line;
                return $output; 
            }elseif($start){ 
                if($line != ""){
                    ob_flush();
                    flush();
                    $output[] = $line; 
                    echo $line."<br/>";
                }
            } 
        } 
    } 
    echo "out of time";
}   
?>
```

Hope this helps anyone with a similar issue.

S.